# mysql if else with a statement as its condition?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate something from the DB level and would like to know if its possible to an if/else or ifnull or other to evaluate this?  IF not what is a good approach?

Is it possible to do something this way?

I've tried several ways, but here is my latest example.

```
IF (SELECT markups.markup FROM markups LIMIT 1) 
THEN
    SELECT ((SELECT AVG(products.price) FROM products WHERE products.code = "8G435G232AB") * (SELECT markups.markup FROM markups LIMIT 1)) + (SELECT AVG(products.price) FROM products WHERE products.code = "8G435G232AB") AS code_8G435G232AB FROM products ORDER BY products.code LIMIT 1
ELSE
    SELECT AVG(products.price) FROM products WHERE products.code = "8G435G232AB"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql for this purpose

The if statement chekcm if there are markups if so it tales the firwst query into a user defined variable `@sql`

and the executes it (see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html))

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT markups.markup FROM markups)
, @sql:=' SELECT ((SELECT AVG(products.price) FROM products WHERE products.code = "8G435G232AB") * (SELECT markups.markup FROM markups LIMIT 1)) + (SELECT AVG(products.price) FROM products WHERE products.code = "8G435G232AB") AS code_8G435G232AB FROM products ORDER BY products.code LIMIT 1'
,@sql:='SELECT AVG(products.price) FROM products WHERE products.code = "8G435G232AB"');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: thanks!  this works in mysql but now I have to figure out how to pass in through PHP.  I guess I should have mentioned that I was using PHP, sorry!

Comment: you can use mltiquery like for mysqli https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php  and please [accept the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers9

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @nbk

After brushing up on multi_query() I got it working doing the following

```
        $sql = " SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT markups.markup FROM markups)
                                , @sql:='SELECT ((SELECT AVG(products.price) FROM products WHERE products.code = ''8G435G232AB'') * (SELECT markups.markup FROM markups LIMIT 1)) + (SELECT AVG(products.price) FROM products WHERE products.code = ''8G435G232AB'') AS code_8G435G232AB FROM products ORDER BY products.code LIMIT 1'
                                
                                , @sql:='SELECT AVG(products.price) FROM products WHERE products.code = ''8G435G232AB'''); ";

        $sql .= "PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; ";
        $sql .= "EXECUTE stmt; ";
        $sql .= "DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; ";

        if($cnx->multi_query($sql)){
            do {
                if ($res = $cnx->store_result()) {
                    $averageQuery = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)[0];
                    $res->free();
                }
            } while ($cnx->more_results() && $cnx->next_result());
        }
```